# Connect yii2 with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new to Yii2. Can anyone tell me how to configure YII2 with mongodb and how to establish connection between YII2 and mongodb? I have tried to download the mongodb package from git hub and tried to run the following command

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb "*"
```

In the command prompt inside the root folder where I have installed Yii2 but I get the following error

```
 Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
 Problem 1
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching      package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 == 2.0.0.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0].
```

Comment: You need to follow the install guide http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html follow it step by step

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are trying to install it through command prompt then try the following command which using composer

```
composer require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb "*"
```

This works in my windows 8 environment.

To ignore dependency errors while installing the package use `--ignore-platform-refs` switch:

```
composer require --ignore-platform-refs --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-mongodb "*"
```

Comment: The MongoDB package is not the one causing the problem, that is installing fine, he is suffering problems because he didn't follow the install tutorial correctly

Comment: Thanks. You saved my time. :))

Answer (score 1):

Seems like problem was with yii2 composer dependencies, Kindly RUN this command in your console to add global dependencies,

**1)** **composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.1.1"**

**2)** Add **"yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "~2.0.0"** in your composer.json file

**3)** Now run **composer install** or **composer update**

**4)** **Composer install** will only install require packages in your composer file but **composer update** will also check if there is any new release for your packages that you mentioned in composer.js and then install the new release.

**5)** now add below code in your common/config/main.php file

```
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
        'mongodb' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
        ],
    ],
];
```

Now is the time to test either mongoDb working or not.

```
$collection = Yii::$app->mongodb->getCollection('customer');
$collection->insert(['name' => 'John Smith', 'status' => 1]);
```

For further information Please follow below link,

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb

Comment: 'dsn' => 'mongodb://developer:password@localhost:27017/mydatabase'
If you are expecting to authenticate against the "admin" database, I would suggest removing both "/mydatabase" from the URI string. The driver already defaults to authenticate against the "admin" database. If you do wish to specify a different database, you can either do so via the URI string (where you're currently indicating that you want to auth against the database named "mydatabase") or the authSource option (specified as either a query string parameter in the URI string or via the options array).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you must also have the MongoDB extension installed in PHP for this plugin to work:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb.php

Answer (score -3):

```
'mongodb' => [
        'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/vinagex',
        'options' => [
            "username" => "vinagex",
            "password" => "vinagex"
        ]
    ],
```