# how to display mongodb data to yii2 table?

Tags: mongodb, yii2

I want to display MongoDB User collection data into yii2 tablle. When i run, it doesn't show any data output, [only show 5 empty rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76WPF.png) (i have 5 rows in User collection)

Im new in mongodb. I have tried displaying it using the usual format as I display data from mysql (only the query I changed).It doesn't seem to work well, but doesn't display any error message

Here my code :

Model/User.php

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
  public $_id;
  public $username;
  public $password;

  public static function collectionName()
  { return ['latihan', 'User']; }

  public function attributes()
  {
    return [
       '_id',
       'id',
       'username',
       'password',
       'role',        
    ];
  }

   public function fields() 
   {
     return [
        '_id' => function() { return (string)$this->_id; },
        'id',
        'username',
        'password',
        'role',  
      ];
  }

  public function rules()
  {
  return [
      ['role', 'default', 'value' => 10],
      [['_id', 'username', 'password'], 'safe'],
    ];
   }

  public static function findOne($condition)
  {
    $query = new Query();
    $data = $query->from(static::collectionName())->where($condition)->one();
    $user = new User();
    $user->id = $data['id'];
    $user->username = $data['username'];
    $user->password = $data['password'];
    $user->role = $data['role'];

    return $user;
}
```

HomeController.php

```
public function actionAbout()
{
    $user = User::find()->all();
    return $this->render('about', ['model' => $user]); 
    }
}
```

About.php

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Aksi</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

<?php $i = 1; foreach($model as $field){ ?>
    <tr>
    <?php $username =$field->username; ?>
        <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td>
            <td><?= $field->username; ?></td>
            <td><?= $field->password; ?></td>
            <td>
            <a href="<?php echo Url::to(['/home/editabout']).'?id='.$field->id;?>"> Update</a> | 
            <a href="<?php echo Url::to(['/home/deleteabout']).'?id='.$field->id; ?>"> Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It does not work because you implemented settings these fields in `User::findOne()`, but in controller you're using `User::find()->all()`.

Answer (score -1):

from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27353394/connect-yii2-with-mongodb)
first you must add
[yii2-mongodb](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb) in your composer.json file and update composer with this command **composer update**

then you can edit **main-local.php** file and overwrite the **db** component.

```
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
            'options' => [
                "username" => "Username",
                "password" => "Password"
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

**+** if you want to use both mysql (deafult connection) and mongodb you must  dont overwrite **db** component and just add mongodb.

```
return [
    //....
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            .... mysql db config (default)
        ],
        'mongodb' => [
            'class' => '\yii\mongodb\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mongodb://@localhost:27017/mydatabase',
            'options' => [
                "username" => "Username",
                "password" => "Password"
            ]
        ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: @HanifBudiarti see your database, maybe you have empty values

Comment: im pretty sure if my db not empty, i have 5 row with each value in User document

Comment: @HanifBudiarti no, check your columns are empty or not

Comment: my columns are not empty